# Merge Dataframes using List of Columns (Pandas Vlookup)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to lookup several columns from another dataframe that I have in a list to bring them over to my main dataframe, essentially doing a "v-lookup" of ~30 columns using ID as the key or lookup value for all columns.

However, for the columns that are the same between the two dataframes, I don't want to bring over the duplicate columns but have those values be filled in df1 from df2.

I've tried below:

```
df = pd.merge(df,df2[['ID', [look_up_cols]]] ,
                     on ='ID', 
                     how ='left', 
#suffixes=(False,False)
)
```

but it brings in the shared columns from df2 when I want df2's values filled into the same columns in df1.

I've tried also created a dictionary with the column pairs from each df and doing this for loop to lookup each item in the dictionary (lookup_map) in the other df using ID as the key:

```
for col in look_up_cols:
    df1[col] = df2['ID'].map(lookup_map)
```

but this just returns NaNs.

Comment: can you just append 'ID' to your look_up_cols?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like the following:

```
df = pd.merge(df,df2[look_up_cols + ['ID']] ,
                     on ='ID', 
                     how ='left')
```

This just adds the `ID` column to the `look_up_cols` list and thereby allows it to be used in the `merge` function

Comment: @tonytone Can you show what `look_up_cols` looks like?

Comment: it's list with 20 names of columns from df2.